# Any way to catch exception from .dll in .net

Tags: .net, wpf, debugging, app-config

I'm trying to restructure an app.config file, adding some custom tags. It's rather copmplex structure, like three pieces of *ConfigurationElementCollection* nested within each other.
On program run, it's silently dying, outputting the single line like `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException occurred in System.Configuration.dll`. 
It's most certainly not enough to determine the cause. How do I get more information of it, at least the text of exception?

**P.S.** This is WPF application

Comment: Where is it outputting that line? Have you tried running your application under debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio Ctrl+Alt+e and tick System.Configuration.ConfigurationException under Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Comment: Thanks, though it now breaks, when it was unhandled by user (which was the case).

Comment: I meant that it should just break there, nothing about the error message, isn't it so?

Comment: It should break and show the small exception window, where you can click 'view details'. Under details also the message of the exception is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I would enable [debugging the .net source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) and see why it's throwing the exception

Comment: Upwoted, interesting article. Though, I don't see the System.Configuration .dll in that list of dlls available for inner look, and I'm too lazy to go and see, if it can be looked into, as I managed to step through the problem :)

Comment: There is always Reflector Cost or Just Code (Free) Decompilers

Comment: I meant **look into** as the option of VS debugger. I was interested in debugging, not reverse engineering itself.

Comment: Yes I understand thats what my first suggestion was, just throwing another out there